# Using a RegEx to escape LaTeX special characters

Tags: pdftex

OK so I'm writing this small app that needs to incorporate the data from a csv into a LaTeX document that includes the data as a table. I've figured out most of the basics about using LaTeX tables, my issue is how to go about escaping whatever reserved LaTeX characters may appear inside the plaintext. Essentially, I want to be able to use sed on the raw csv file before incorporating into the LaTeX, avoiding any issues. However, I'm not very well versed at writting regexes (reading Mastering Reg. Expr.), so I was hoping someone already had a solution to my problem.

So as a quick example, if given the string `introducing #43 & all the others` the expression would output `introducing \#43 \& all the others`.

I'm not asking anyone to go and do thorough research into LaTeX, I'm just posting this here in case my problem has already been solved. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: I will try to provide a more concrete example/explanation.

Generally, this is the procedure, I have three files, `before`, `after`, and `content`. `before` contains all the LaTeX opening information, such as the following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=5cm, bottom=3cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\maketitle

  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|p{4cm}|}
```

Unsurprisingly, `after` contains all the closing LaTeX information:

```
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

As you can probably guess, `content` contains the csv data I want to use in the table:

```
1,19th Jan 2014,foo,bar,baz,qux,#1 information & other stuff
...
43,21st Nov 2015,quxx,whatever,comes,next,#43 information & other stuff
```

Now, either by using a bash script or a php cli app, I plan to assemble the files in the obvious order, `before`, `content`, `after`.

So my biggest challenge is to do the following:

1. Change the delimiter in the csv file from `,` to `&`, while escaping whatever `&`'s that already exist.
2. Escape all LaTeX special characters that exist in the csv file before inserting them.

After this, I plan to compile, outputting a pdf file.

I would really appreciate thoughts on the issue: anything ranging from criticisms of my approach to direct solutions would be helpful.

I hope this is more clear, and thanks again (to whoever replies).

**Edit**: changed file names from `header` and `footer` to `before` and `after` (respectively).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A simple example of how you want to use the CSV file would improve your question and make suggesting a solution easier.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a script (python, perl, sed, awk ...). You probably shouldn't call your before and after files `header.tex` and `footer.tex` since those are technical layout objects. How about `before.tex` and `after.tex`?

Comment: I see, let me do some research into scripting. Which of the technologies you listed would you recommend for someone with minimal experience? Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly what you searching but there is some tools to read csv and generate the latex table code like the excel plugin excel2latex and online like www.tablesgenerator.com that may help you.